# jquery not responding to click event on div of certain class

Tags: jquery, click

Or at least I think that's the problem.

Full disclosure, there's AngularJS involved a bit as well. I don't know why that would make a difference, but I wanted it out there.

Here is the page code:

```
    <div ng-repeat="inquiry in faq" class="inquiry" ng-if="$index > 0">
        <div class="question">{{inquiry.question}}</div>
        <div class="answer">{{inquiry.answer}}</div>
    </div>
```

Then I have this inside the `$(document).ready(function() {` block:

```
$('.question').click(function(){
    alert("hi");
//  $(this).siblings( ".answer" ).toggle();
});
```

As you can see, I commented out the second line, and this should simply alert. Nada. Nothing. No errors in console. I've tried this as well:

```
$('.inquiry').on("click", ".question", function() {
    alert("bob");                                   
});
```

(inquiry is the parent div of question)

Nothing. I might as well be clicking plain text.

I've used this in the past just fine, but today it doesn't want to work.

Oh, and I include jquery before this script file. So that's not it.

Comment: is there any error in your console?

Comment: There are no errors in console.

Comment: can you use `ng-click` and try, if that works

Comment: tried that. I did ng-click=toggleAnswer() and put the function toggleAnswer in the document.ready block. Nada.

Comment: This isn't a select dropdown.

Comment: Can you show me how you have implemented by using ng-click in your controller ?

Comment: Sure, but I can't at the moment. I'll have to get that up later.